# PyQt5 setText

Tags: qt5, c++

Я совсем недавно начал изучать Qt (PyQt5), и у меня возникла проблема. У меня есть ***QPushButton***, и я хочу изменять текст на нем при клике. Те можно создать класс, наследующийся от ***QPushButton***, но должно быть что-то совсем простое. В идеале, что-то типа:

```
b.clicked.connect(b.setText(newText))
```

Но так нельзя, конечно.
Как всегда, всем спасибо!

Comment: Не могу ответить сам, поэтому напишу здесь. Можно написать так:

    b.clicked.connect(lambda f : b.setText(text))

Comment: А зачем PyQt?

Почему не PySide?

Comment: @theluckyemil вы совершенно правы, обертка в данном случае отличное решение

Answer (score 1):

Вот достаточно подробно про события: http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/eventsandsignals